# Make moderator message templates adapt for recidivism

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, moderator-tools

Can the templates available for moderators to use when privately contacting users for serious matters have versions for *repeat* offences?

Currently, the templates are written with a style befitting a first offence. However, if the user re-offends, the moderator must edit a good part of the message so it makes sense, and to *emphasise* the message - in the (all too often vain) hope that the message will successfully make its way all the way through to the cerebral cortex of the user.

**For convenience and consistency, it would be good if there were 3 versions of each template.**

For example, for the theoretical offence of "being bad":

1. We have noticed that recently you have been bad. Please don't do that.
2. You were previously contacted about being bad. You have been bad *again*. Please stop being bad!
3. This is the last time you will be contacted about being bad. Any further badness will result in your account being deleted.

This could be done by simply adding more templates, but that would make the list too large (it's 12 already). I'm thinking about a separate radio button group for "first", "second", "third" etc that would cause the relevant version of the template to be used.

I admit it doesn't happen all that often, but it happens, so this change would save time and allow secondary and tertiary messages to be properly worded and consistent.

Comment: The system already knows what strike they're on, drop the radio and have it render based on that

Comment: @random but does the system know what strike they're on *for each offence*? eg if 1st offence was spam, and 2nd was offensive remarks, you'd want the "first" version of each template

Comment: @Bohemian: when would that be the case? If a user was actually spamming, then being rude towards others, wouldn't you want to be more serious towards them?

Comment: There comes a point where the message can consist entirely of: "We told you to stop that.  You didn't.  We're suspending you for N days."

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy probably, but it's up to the mod, who can choose which version to select. It's more like "mild, medium, hot" chilli sauce. Remember that the offences may be years apart, so a first offence tone may be adequate for a "second" offence of a different type to the first. But the point is it would be nice if it was easily selectable.

Comment: +1 just for [hot chili sauce](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hF18Y.jpg)

Comment: *recidivism* - such a meaty $20 word there.

Comment: @Adel good and woody

Answer (score 7):

Honestly anything past the first offense I make it personal. Not because I want to give the problematic user my attention, but because wow holy crap I have moderator powers so I'm bigger than you now shut up and sit down and stop being bad or feel my wrath. That's what moderation eventually does to you after you've been in it long enough: instill into you an inescapable superiority complex.

But really, I make it personal because depending on the user it might just take a more personalized message, or a brief conversation in private, for them to see the error of their ways, and as long as it helps someone reform, I feel good. Of course, that will only reform some users and not others, but to those others I say [*"YOU GET NOTHING! YOU LOSE! **GOOD DAY, SIR!**"*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Bl32n6-JXc) And knowing I won't waste any more time on someone who clearly does not want to reform makes me feel just as good. (And even if they try to evade the ban with alt accounts, I just tell them *"I SAID **GOOD DAY!**"*)

In any case, the mod message templates do need some serious reworking at this point. I have a different issue with them, but I can't come up with anything better at the moment hence not posting a feature request of my own.

Comment: this was a good laugh sir

Answer (score 5):

Recidivism happens for one of two reasons:

- They didn't understand what you were trying to communicate with the message, thus throwing another wall of text at them isn't likely to be helpful
- They don't *care* about what you were trying to communicate with the message, and aren't going to care more if you use slightly stronger wording

Either way, you need to (as BoltClock said) figure out what might have happened, and try to explain what you want to get across more simply (for someone that might not have a good comprehension of English), or :

> Okay, I told you not to touch it .. told you not to touch it ... told you not to touch it - **you broke it**.

... along with a suspension.

Another sub set of messages for this really wouldn't be all that helpful in the *vast majority* of recidivism cases that you'll encounter.

The utility aspect of your idea is interesting because it would allow us to actually *track* recidivism better based on the reason for suspension, which might help us better tweak the templates (which Robert is currently working on). I like *that* part of the idea if you want to propose it separately, but I can't really see enough utility to work ratio to implement this as it is.